# WP Magento Fishpig: where is function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, fishpig

I want add Prettyphoto to my blog and I prepare filter:

```
    add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_link', 'sant_prettyadd');

function sant_prettyadd ($content) {
    $content = preg_replace("/<a/","<a rel=\"prettyPhoto[slides]\"",$content,1);
    return $content;
}
```

But where I should looking file function.php ?

Comment: In active theme folder.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, I have active twentytwelve theme but when I chnage file function.php it is not working... Please note that I have integration Magento and Fishpig ...

Comment: Perhaps the file isn't being interpreted because [you gave it the wrong name](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Functions_File). It should be `functions.php`—plural, not singular.

Comment: Hi I checked and it is functions.php not function.php

Answer (score 0):

When WordPress is integrated into Magento, the functions.php file is not used, which means that any code you add to it won't have any effect on the frontend of your blog.

The integration extension is Magento based and uses Magento templates to display your blog. You probably want to add the preg_replace function call to the post view template. This can be found at the following location:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wordpress/post/view.phtml
```

To make changes to this file, first copy it to your custom theme and edit it there. Look for the following line:

```
<?php echo $post->getPostContent() ?>
```

This is the code that retrieves the post content. You can use the preg_replace call here to achieve what you're trying to do.